# How to change assembly version of a dll without rebuilding in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

Can anyone help me out to change the version of a assembly(.dll) without rebuilding it.

I want to re-stamp the assembly version without building it.

Comment: Need more details on what you are trying to do here.

Comment: wanna hack something? :)

Comment: I want to re-stamp the assembly version without building it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have two options;

1. do not sign the assembly and set specific version to false in the project where you have referenced it.
2. create a [Publisher Policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz32563a%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for the assembly and add [bindingRedirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) element to your configuration.

Comment: Daryal thanks for your comments, can you please give the code sample for this.